# Fail to Log Out with google at my navigation drawer (menuitem) activity

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

I'm making an app that allow user to login from my Main Activity  and Log Out from Navigation activity using Facebook and Google+. Everything works fine with facebook. But with google once I Login, I cant logout.Im stuck at navigation activity.

I've already put

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
```

This is my Navigation activity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    promotion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.promo);
    promotion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ShoppingMall.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    setNavigationHeader();    // call setNavigationHeader Method.
    setUserProfile();  // call setUserProfile Method.


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

This is where I put my facebook and google+ LogOut at my drawer

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.profile) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, myProfile.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }  else if (id == R.id.allList) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ShoppingMall.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.location) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } 
else if (id == R.id.logout) {
        StartApplication.logout(HomeActivity.this);
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Main.class);
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } 

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

All is fine except google

Comment: stuck ?? What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: There is no Error occur. I just cant log out back to my Main activity(Login). When I click the logout, it stay on same page.

Comment: if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) { steps....}StartApplication.logout(HomeActivity.this);LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();Log.v("TAG","Logout process completed");  Now start with the following and see if above log is getting printed or not Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Main.class);startActivity(intent);finish();

Comment: It does not getting printed. And like always when i click It still on same page..
 When I try it using facebook. All work fine if I put StartApplication.logout(HomeActivity.this);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); outside IF

Comment: Means statements before StartApplication.logout(HomeActivity.this);LoginManager.getInstance().‌​logOut(); or these statements are giving errors. Do debug where it is breaking. the control may be going out in those logics

Comment: I run the debugger. There is no breaking :/